# Bayes Factor Analysis

Tags: bayesian, bayes-factors

I am new to Bayesian statistics.

I have one group (n=10) with two measurements per subject (before/after a treatment manipulation, i.e., Phase "2" and "3" below).

I originally used linear mixed-effects modeling in R to analyze the data, and the *lsmeans* package for post hoc tests. Here is the output from *lsmeans*:

```
 Phase lsmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 2      0.370 0.292 33.4   -0.223    0.963
 3      0.893 0.273 43.8    0.343    1.443
```

```
contrast  estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 2 - 3     -0.523  0.345 68.8 -1.516  0.1341
```

My question is how can I calculate and interpret the Bayes factor? I think the following is the correct code for running this analysis in R:

```
library(BayesFactor)
1/exp(ttest.tstat(t=-1.52, n1=10, rscale = 0.707)[['bf']])
```

I am not sure what the 'scale r on effect size' is, so clarification on that specifically would be very helpful.

Also, the output I got from the code above is: 1.335257, and I am not sure how to interpret this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have the full data (it seems like it) or just the t statistics (say, it's reported in a paper). If you have the data, then you should do the full Bayesian factor computation with the `BayesFactor::ttestBF()` function.